# LibSVM for Android - garbage collect delay

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection, libsvm

I am using LibSVM.jar and trying to load/run an SVM model on Android.

While loading the model, the garbage collector gradually takes more and more time. Once the model is loaded, and before I even run it on any data, the GC delay peaks but the garbage collector continues to run frequently. I am not sure where all of the memory might be getting allocated (to then be freed again).

Logcat output from start of model load:

```
D/dalvikvm( 4958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1883K, 34% free 17922K/26752K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
D/dalvikvm( 4958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1963K, 33% free 18007K/26752K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
D/dalvikvm( 4958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1886K, 33% free 18152K/26752K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
D/dalvikvm( 4958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1943K, 32% free 18257K/26752K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
```

Logcat output from the end of the model load, continuing indefinitely after:

```
D/dalvikvm(12382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4256K, 12% free 75103K/84828K, paused 545ms, total 545ms
D/dalvikvm(12382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5535K, 14% free 73726K/84828K, paused 548ms, total 548ms
D/dalvikvm(12382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4217K, 12% free 75076K/84828K, paused 534ms, total 534ms
D/dalvikvm(12382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5510K, 14% free 73726K/84828K, paused 479ms, total 479ms
```

I am trying to profile the garbage collection to try and find the error. Will return here to post if I find anything - any help in the meantime would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .jar file (slow due to Java), you can use this JNI wrapper of the original c-based libsvm in Android : https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSvm

I have used this for a while and found the speed is quite acceptable for most applications.